# How to solve unable to locate element NosuchElement

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

```
URL = f'https://www.etsy.com/in-en/c/jewelry/earrings/ear-jackets-and-climbers?ref=pagination&page={page}'

try:
    #Count for every page of website
    URL = URL.format(page)
    browser.get(URL)
    print("Scraping Page:",page)
    
    #xpath of product table
    PATH_1 ='//*[@id="content"]'
    
    #getting total items
    items = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 'PATH_1')
    items = items.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')
    
    #available items in page
    end_product = len(items)
    
    #Count for every product of the page
    for product in range(0,end_product):
        print("Scarping reviews for product",product+1)
        
        #clicking on product
        try:
            items[product].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').click()
        except:
            print('Product link not found')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: we can't run code, we can't see full error which show which line makes problem, and we can't read in your mind. If you want help then you have to describe all details in question.

Comment: `NosuchElement` sometimes needs `time.sleep()` to wait and JavaScript has time to add element, sometimes it may need to `switch_to.frame()` if item is in `<frame>`, sometimes needs to use different `find_xxx`, sometimes needs to scroll to this element, sometimes needs to remove other element which hide it - but without running code it is hard to say what make problem.

Comment: is this code really work? If you use `.format(page)` then don't use prefix `f` in `f-string`

Comment: you have stupid mistake - typo -  you use string `"PATH_1"` instead of variable `PATH_1` - and full error message shows it.  - `browser.find_element(By.XPATH, PATH_1)`